# How to determine for every wall in a 2D tilemap where's the "inside"?

Tags: unity, tilemap

I'm working on an ARPG, and I'd like to implement a **"fading walls" system** similar to Diablo II's.

Let's say I have this tilemap, where

- Black tiles are walls,
- Brown tiles are floors,
- White tiles are... nothing.

[image]

I could already achieve that **every wall is faded which is on the bottom half of the screen**. (The player is centered on the screen).

[image]

But I don't want to hide the walls **further away from the camera than the player**, even if it's on the bottom half of the screen. (Marked with red, above)

For this, I decided to calculate every walls' **"inwards direction"**.

And the walls with **inward direction pointing downwards** on the screen are **always shown**, even if they are on the bottom half of the screen

Every wall already has their neighbours' type stored because I use them to determine their visuals.

Could you help me in figuring out a nice way to do this?

Or maybe the better question would be: how to nicely implement a Diablo II like wall fading system? :|

Comment: Sounds like the dot product could solve this issue.

Comment: @ChrisSprance Could you elaborate please? :)